# Longest common path between k graphs

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I was looking at interview problems and come across this one, failed to find a liable solution.

Actual question was asked on [Leetcode discussion](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/1215680/Amazon-Onsite-Question).

Given multiple school children and the paths they took from their school to their homes, find the longest most common path (paths are given in order of steps a child takes).

Example:

```
child1 : a -> g -> c -> b -> e
child2 : f -> g -> c -> b -> u
child3 : h -> g -> c -> b -> x

result = g -> c -> b
```

Note: There could be multiple children.The input was in the form of steps and childID. For example input looked like this:

```
(child1, a)
(child2, f)
(child1, g)
(child3, h)
(child1, c)
...
```

Some suggested longest common substring can work but it will not example -

```
1 a-b-c-d-e-f-g
2 a-b-c-x-y-f-g
3 m-n-o-p-f-g
4 m-x-o-p-f-g
1 and 2 will give abc, 3 and 4 give pfg
now ans will be none but ans is fg
```

it's like graph problem, how can we find longest common path between k graphs ?

Comment: Were the answers helpful? Let us know if you need any more or different inputs.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1: With Graph construction**

Consider this example:

```
1 a-b-c-d-e-f-g
2 a-b-c-x-y-f-g
3 m-n-o-p-f-g
4 m-x-o-p-f-g
```

Draw a directed weighted graph.

[image]

I am a lazy person. So, I have not drawn the direction arrows but believe they are invisibly there. Edge weight is 1 if not marked on the arrow.

> Give the length of longest chain with each edge in the chain having Maximum Edge Weight `MEW`.

- `MEW` is 4, our answer is FG.
- Say AB & BC had edge weight 4, then ABC should be the answer.

The below example, which is the case of `MEW` < #children, should output ABC.

```
1 a-b-c-d-e-f-g
2 a-b-c-x-y-f-g
3 m-n-o-p-f-h
4 m-x-o-p-f-i
```

If some kid is like me, the kid will keep roaming multiple places before reaching home. In such cases, you might see `MEW` > #children and the solution would become complicated. I hope all the children in our input are obedient and they go straight from school to home.

[image]

---

**Approach 2: Without Graph construction**

If luckily the problem mentions that the longest common piece of path should be present in the paths of all the children i.e. strictly `MEW` == #children then you can solve by easier way. Below picture should give you clue on what to do.

[image]

Take the below example

```
1 a-b-c-d-e-f-g
2 a-b-c-x-y-f-g
3 m-n-o-p-f-g
4 m-x-o-p-f-g
```

**Method 1:**

Get longest common graph for first two: a-b-c, f-g (Result 1)

Get longest common graph for last two: p-f-g (Result 2)

Using Result 1 & 2 we get: f-g (Final Result)

**Method 2:**

Get longest common graph for first two: a-b-c, f-g (Result 1)

Take Result 1 and next graph i.e. m-n-o-p-f-g:  f-g (Result 2)

Take Result 2 and next graph i.e. m-x-o-p-f-g:  f-g (Final Result)

*The beauty of the approach without graph construction is that even if kids roam same pieces of paths multiple times, we get the right solution.*

---

If you go a step ahead, you could combine the approaches and use approach 1 as a sub-routine in approach 2.

Comment: I got your concept but didn't understand last image u shared

Comment: @PankajSharma: Updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a directed graph `g` with an edge `a->b` present if and only if it is present in all individual paths, then drop all nodes with degree zero.

- The graph `g` will have have no cycles. If it did, the same cycle would be present in all individual paths, and a path has no cycles by definition.
- In addition, all in-degrees and out-degrees will be zero or one. For example, if a node `a` had in-degree greater than one, there would be two edges representing two students arriving at `a` from two different nodes. Such edges cannot appear in `g` by construction.

The graph will look like a disconnected collection of paths. There may be multiple paths with maximum length, or there may be none (an empty path if you like).

In the Python code below, I find all common paths and return one with maximum length. I believe the whole procedure is linear in the number of input edges.

---

```
import networkx as nx

path_data = """1 a-b-c-d-e-f-g
2 a-b-c-x-y-f-g
3 m-n-o-p-f-g
4 m-x-o-p-f-g"""
paths = [line.split(" ")[1].split("-") for line in path_data.split("\n")]
num_paths = len(paths)

# graph h will include all input edges
# edge weight corresponds to the number of students
# traversing that edge
h = nx.DiGraph()
for path in paths:
  for (i, j) in zip(path, path[1:]):
    if h.has_edge(i, j):
      h[i][j]["weight"] += 1
    else:
      h.add_edge(i, j, weight=1)

# graph g will only contain edges traversed by all students
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from((i, j) for i, j in h.edges if h[i][j]["weight"] == num_paths)

def longest_path(g):
  # assumes g is a disjoint collection of paths
  all_paths = list()
  for node in g.nodes:
    path = list()
    if g.in_degree[node] == 0:
      while True:
        path.append(node)
        try:
          node = next(iter(g[node]))
        except:
          break
    all_paths.append(path)
  if not all_paths:
    # handle the "empty path" case
    return []
  return max(all_paths, key=len)

print(longest_path(g))
# ['f', 'g']
```

Comment: it's a good approach but I think we need to take care of case when a child pass through same path multiple times in his/her journey

Comment: You may want to clarify the wording in the question, e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path). I assumed that you meant path in a technical sense, since you mentioned graph theory.